# Complexity of search operation in NoSql Databases

Tags: azure-table-storage, nosql

I am relatively new to NoSql databases. My query is that if I want to search or retrieve a data record say a data record with name XYZ what will be the complexity of this operation(database could be azure tables). Whether it would be faster than SQL databases or not? And how is this search implemented.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entity in an Azure Table has a partition key and row key. With careful planning, you can choose good values for the partition key and row key to match the way you need to update and retrieve the data. If you know the partition key and row key of an entity, it can be retrieved efficiently. Otherwise, you are potentially scanning an entire partition or entire table to retrieve entities. See this article for information about designing your partitions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh508997.aspx. See this article for information about performance targets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249410.aspx.